# occursMostOften(int[] a) - java

Tags: java, arrays

im trying to find the number that occurs the most in a given array of int. here is my code, it works but there are some inconsistencies. also, if u can let me know how i can make it better, i think my code is too long!!

```
public static int countOccurrences(int[] a, int x) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        if(a[i] == x) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public static int occursMostOften(int[] a) {
    int[] count = new int[a.length];
    boolean[] duplicate = new boolean[a.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length;i++) {
        if(duplicate[i] != true) {
            count[i] = countOccurrences(a,a[i]);
            duplicate[i] = true;
        }
    }
    return a[maxIndex(count)];
}
private static int maxIndex(int[] a) {
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<a.length;i++) {
        if(a[i-1]<a[i]) max = i;
    }
    return max;     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is an assignment (which I assume it is), your code meets the requirements, though not the most optimal.

If you have learned about a data structure called a Map, use that instead. The *key* in the map will be the value in the array, and the *value* in the map the count of times you have seen this value.

This will reduce the complexity of your code. Sequence of operations are:

For each value in the array

1. If the value exits in the map, update the count
2. If not, create a new entry with a count of one

At the end, you can iterate through the map to find the most occuring value.

Comment: No, I can think of an O(n log n) algorithm, but that's best left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Your code perform linear scan of full array for each non duplicate number. With array of size `n` that has `n` distinct values complexity of your code will be O(n^2).

You can do it better in O(n) with following algorithm:

- Iterate through all numbers in array
- For each number add it to the map (`Map<Integer, Integer>`) that holds number and it count
- If number exist in the map get current count, increment, and put back to the map
- If number not exists just oput that entry with count 1 to the map
- After all iterations complete, retrieve values and fins maximum.

Comment: I'm not sure, but seems we can achieve results on plain arrays faster. Need to think.